# TS type-check error on dynamic key in record

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

Typescript throws an error `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'.` when explicitly checking if property is not a string using a variable key.

```
let params: Record<string, string | string[]>;
const key = 'test';

// This works
if (params && typeof params['test'] !== 'string') {
  params['test'].forEach((element: string) => {});
}

// This fails
if (params && typeof params[key] !== 'string') {
  // FAILS with "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'."
  params[key].forEach((element: string) => {});
}
```

How should I type/check that a property is an array and forEach can run?

Comment: I don't have an error in ts playground

Comment: Try it here https://playcode.io/typescript/ - I see an error there. Also I have the error in VSCode, hence the question :P

Comment: What typescript version do you use? Seems that it is a bug related to older version.

Comment: 4.7.3 - sorry should have specified in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript compiler do not understood this patterns cause you can technically modify `params[key]` value anytime. So typeguard does not work in this case. At least that was the reason with older typescript version, maybe there is other way now.

To fix that you can assign `params[key]` to variable and then do the checks:

```
let params: Record<string, string | string[]> = {}
const key = 'test';


const value = params[key]
if (typeof value !== 'string') {
  value.forEach((element: string) => {});
}
```